# Where can external libraries be added to C code?

Tags: c, dll, static-libraries, external

I am answering this homework problem I need some help with.

[image]

As I understand, external libraries can be added in two places in a C file: the top, with an #include statement, and in a function body, with dlopen().

I'm not sure if this is the correct interpretation of the problem, and if it is, if there are other places I may have missed.

Thank you for any insights :)

Comment: You'll need to consult your lecture notes to understand what the teacher wants you to regurgitate. (3a) Does zero count? You don't add libraries to the code; you add them to the build process, or load them at runtime. (3b) There are no places, so you shouldn't get more points for listing zero places. (3c) And since there are no places, there are no disadvantages or advantages to those zero places. Clearly, my interpretation of what "libraries in code" means doesn't mean what they think it does. Work out what you've been taught, but I have reservations about the usefulness of that information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler would you consider headers with static inline functions or function like macros as libraries? I believe some parts of the standard C *library* are also implemented that way.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: 'Header-only libraries' are real, especially in the C++ world.  They're rare but not impossible in C.  I still regard them first and foremost as headers rather than libraries — they provide their services without using a library.  Whether this was discussed in the lecture notes is something I can't tell.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: This also raises the question "what is a library".  Does 'parts of the standard C library' being implemented like that mean "the standard C library is (all) implemented like that"?  No; there's still a separate standard C library.  There are complex constraints on C libraries.  You don't have to include a header to get access to most of the services of the library.  You are permitted to include an appropriate declaration (that matches what the standard says) and call the function even without the header being included. That means the library must provide the functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the common idea of a library (a `.so` file or `.a` file) is a part of the implementation. This interpretation of the word "library" is correct in the OS context. For C, this is not necessary. In fact, one could have an implementation where libraries are not linked in such a way. The implementation might not even be compiled. In that case I am not sure if just including the prototype of the function and not including the header would work. I am not sure on this part, but does the standard allow this?(I am sure the standard allows some functions to be declared as macros)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but then again, OP has added the `dll` and `static-libraries` to the question. So I think your interpretation (and hence the comment) is correct. There is one possibility though - `#pragma comment(lib, "library.0.lib")`. I am again not sure if this is standard.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: the standard allows functions to be declared as macros, but it requires every function to be implemented as a function.  There are a few exceptions — `va_arg()` is one such; `offsetof()` is another.  In both cases, it's because the macro takes arguments which are not simple values; `va_arg()` takes a type name; `offsetof()` takes a type and a 'member designator' as arguments.